# Marking mulitple cells as relevant based of a certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have an event-planning spreadsheet; I have a list of activities in the first column and types of events in the first row.

I have been going through each individual cell and marking a 1 in each one if it applies (if you can do trivia at a 40-55 birthday party then there is a 1 in the cell)

What I want to be able to do is have some way I can mark multiple things at once. For example; “topics from a hat” pretty much can fit pretty much any group event that has 6 or more people. I want a “group” button so it marks off the activity in any of the cells I have marked as a group event. Same thing goes for events, if you can do an “all-you-can-eat spaghetti”, then you can also have an “all-you-can-eat potato bar”.

I don’t want to have to go in each one and mark a 1, I just want to have a button or cell I can mark and it will mark the corresponding activities.

If anyone has any suggestions to make this more efficient, please let me know, it has been very time consuming and there are still a lot more activities and events to add to the list.

[google sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Ud_vXsv5SNMfLFiTO8mYBnYvgYmJLZX3dnaU8FjgTg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What about using a QUERY() function in row 2 and use row one of a separate tab/sheet to define some criteria. =QUERY({'Card games'1!A1:Z; 'board games'!A1:Z}, "Select * where Col2 = '" & A2 & "', 1) as a simple version.  You may have to change your tables format and I suspect make it work for your intention, but maybe you get the idea.

Comment: Don't fully understand the reply but at least you have provided me more information that I can use to continue to investigate. I couldn't think of how to search the question, so at least now i know that  i should look into the =query function

Comment: Also note combining multiple ranges on different sheets via an array with the { range1 ; range2 } option.  See [Using Arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) for more information on that.  For the QUERY() function, see [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) and also [this article](https://anandexcels.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/query-function-in-google-sheets/) which may be good.  The [explanations here](http://codingisforlosers.com/google-sheets-query-function/) have been helpful as well. (none of these are mine)